# Converting formula into linear expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently conducted an experiment aimed at calculating the Earth's magnetic field.
A compass was placed inside a coil and the apparatus was aligned east-west. When current was applied to the coil, the deflection of the compass was the vector addition of the Earth's magnetic field and the magnetic field created by the coil.

To negate the error, I took multiple measurements with constant current and varied the compass position in relation to the coil. Recording the deflection angle and distance from the coil.

I have the following formulas the relate the deflection angle to the distance $x$ from the coil:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{Bc}{Be} $$

$$ Bc = \frac{ \mu NIR^2}{2(R^2+x^2)^(3/2)} $$

I have found articles on similar experiments and it's mentioned that these two formulas can be combined into a linear equation: $$ Y = mX + A$$

My guess is that $ Y = \theta $ and $ X = x $. This function could then be graphed and the slope would give a more accurate result of $Be$

However, there was no guidance on how to combine these formulas into the linear form. Why does this offer better accuracy? Can anyone point me in the right direction on this transformation?

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. Could you give a few data points $(x_i,\theta_i)$ ? The problem is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to plot a relation between $\theta$ and $x$, it seems that directly, your relation looks like $\tan\theta=\frac{\mu NIR^2}{2B_e(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}}$. Now what you could do is let $Y=\tan\theta$ and $X=(x^2+R^2)^{-3/2}$ (you'll have to carry out this calculation for all your data points and essentially make two extra columns in your observation table). Then, the relation would look like $Y=mX$ where the slope $m$ is $\frac{\mu NIR^2}{2B_e}$.

The reason you want a linear form is mostly just because it's easy to graph and get a slope from. Once you find the slope, you can substitute known values and find $B_e$.

Answer (score 0):

You must be very careful with such a problem because what you measure is $\theta$ as a function of $x$ and **not** any possible transform of $\theta$.

This means that you model is
$$\theta=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{\left(R^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) \qquad \text{where} \quad k=\frac{ \mu NIR^2}{2Be}$$

So, in a preliminary step, let $Y=\tan(\theta)$, $X=\frac{1}{\left(R^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}$ and you have a linear regression
$$Y=k X \implies k=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\,Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i}$$ but this is only an estimate. Now, you need to start a nonlinear regression to obtain the most probable value of $k$ and then the best $Be$.

If you have no access to such a tool, I could show how to do it with algebra.